# Etymology/origin of the term 'blazes over'?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, sports

In soccer (football), commentators often exclaim that "Player X blazes over the goal"  or "...just *blazes* it over, really poor shot..."
It's also found in written form, either in live text coverage or in match summaries, as in this quote:

> Gakpo goes on a mazy run before laying it off to Blind, who blazes over. It's a poor effort.

(From [as.com](https://en.as.com/soccer/netherlands-vs-usmnt-live-team-usa-updates-score-stats-qatar-world-cup-2022-n/))

Basically, it refers to a shot that goes (high?) over the crossbar, most often when the attacking player should have scored. I wish to know where the term came from and when it was first used (in print or otherwise).

Comment: Not sure but there are various things online https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/blaze-over.3069041/

Comment: To me it seems obvious that "blaze" a metaphor for a missile or meteor traveling rapidly, and "over" refers to it going over the goal instead of into it.